# Which texmf directory to use for non-texlive deb-package

Tags: installing, ubuntu, texmf, debian

I'd like to provide a collection of packages/classes/fonts in a custom .deb package, i.e. that is not part of texlive.

Which directory should I choose for installing?

texlive tells me to use `TEXMLOCAL` for additional packages which is normally `/usr/local/share/texmf`. But debian says `/usr/local` is not allowed for deb-packages.

Comment: Put it in `~/texmf/`.  `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` will tell you what the 'personal' base directory is.  You may need to create it; you could do, e.g., `mkdir -p ~/texmf/{bibtex,doc,fonts,tex,texdoc}` (depending on your needs: you may require other directories -- just make it mimic the directory structure of your system `texmf`, including the subdirectories!).

Comment: A deb package that installs in ~ ? Not really ;).

Comment: Sorry: you want to *create* a `.deb` package for Debian/etc.?  And it will work regardless of what kind of TeX Live installation people have?  I think this is the wrong approach.  Make a `.tds.zip` file and let users decide where they want to install it.  That way it is not a Debian-specific thing, but is useful to anyone who has a TDS-compliant TeX installation.

Comment: For instance, I would not want to use a `.deb` since I installed TeX Live from TUG, and I wouldn't want your file to install in `/usr/local/share/texmf` on my system.  Also `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` does not return that dir for me.

Comment: I'd like to have a `.deb` package because it also needs to install some fonts etc. and i wanted to make install as easy as possible. What about `TEXMFMAIN`? Btw. I also provide a `.tds.zip` and an install script.

Comment: Ah, OK.  But, well, I didn't know about `.deb`'s not supposed to go in `/usr/local`, but that seems to be a serious problem since that's where TeX Live often lives (although I gather some prefer to install in it `/opt`).  `TEXMFMAIN` for me is `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf`....  I still prefer the idea of installing a personal collection of fonts and files in `TEXMFLOCAL`, which can of course include things like fonts, but I guess that's no good for a `.deb`.

Comment: Now, my solution is to use `/usr/local/` and add an explicit`lintian` override to prevent errors from installation programs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating `.deb` files, which are a Debian/Ubuntu not a TeX area.